# Android Web App : Position:fixed broken?

Tags: html, css, android, webkit, position

I'm in the process of developping a Web Application for mobiles. I
went with web applications because to me it seems a winning situation
having to develop one application that could run also on iPhone /
Windows Mobile / Palm etc.

I started testing today after a few days of doing concepts, ideas and
designs and what I wanted to do was have a menu that sticks at the
bottom of the page. Exactly like the menu on the bottom in this iPhone
application screenshot :

[image]

Using CSS, I though it would be really easy to do this. Only using
position:fixed; bottom:0; would have done the trick but I have found
it doesn't behave the same on mobile browsers

I tried to split my page in 2 sections : 1 would be a scrollable div
(for the content) and the other one would be the bottom menu.
Scrollable divs also do not work on Android. I also tried using frames
with no luck either. Does anyone know of any way to re-create a menu
that would stick to the bottom of a page for mobile phones?

Comment: you said you would post back if one of the solutions worked - I have a similar issue and would like to know which option to try - thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

On my Android N1 with CyanogenMod i had this trouble too and the fix:

```
   <meta
     name="viewport"
     content="width=100%,
     initial-scale=1,
     maximum-scale=1,
     minimum-scale=1,
     user-scalable=no"/>
```

Specifically the `user-scalable=no;` part, you can also put `0` instead of `no`.

Interestingly this breaks androids rendering of buttons, but all you have to do is set a background color to buttons.

Comment: I've had a lot of problems on many devices using user-scalable=no. When using this I have noticed that select boxes become completely unusable.

Comment: Note that the correct syntax for the viewport meta content attribute uses a comma to separate values, not a semi-colon.

Comment: Unfortunately my proposed edit correcting for the above comment was rejected. Since there seems to be doubt on this point here is a [reference to the specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#parsing-algorithm) which states "authors should be using comma in order to ensure content works as expected in all UAs".

Answer (score 17):

Just add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

to the page and you're set for Android 2.2+. This worked on a page I was testing on my phone. Source: [When can I use CSS position:fixed?](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed)

Comment: Note that this will stop users from being able to zoom in/out on the page (which, by the looks of your question, should be desired anyway).

Answer (score 4):

This is supposed to work :)
http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/

Comment: That was actually super cool, and it does fix, but holy cow it's tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Just got an upgrade to Android 2.2 (Froyo) on my HTC Desire, and I'm happy to say that position fixed now works, at least when you use the viewport meta tag to set initial-scale and width. Still doesn't seem to work on regular web pages though.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that using the meta name in your html header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

you'll have a fixed div on scrolling vertical and horizontal on Android 2.2, 2.3 and up
and iOS 4 and up.
I made an example here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/908148/website/test-scroll.html

Comment: broken link and no useful fix