# Position:fixed breaks font-size on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, css-position

I'm working on a site for mobile devices. Because differing resolutions and such, the idea is to keep font sizes at the browser default size (100%). This `font-size: 100%` works as planned (i.e. the text is readable in a mobile browser, not tiny) in `#content`. However, the text in `#header` is tiny and unreadable. Why the difference? Is it because `#header` has `position:fixed`? If so, is there a work-around or better practice to make the header text the same size as `#content` that is mobile friendly? Thanks.

CSS:

```
body, html {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   font-size: 100%;
}
#main {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   font-size: 100%;
}
#header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background: black;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
#content {
   width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='main'>
   <div id='header'>header here</div>
   <div id='content'>content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The idea is to prevent the header from being scrolled where it can't be seen by the user. I know my code won't do this, but this code is modified from the original for this question.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast, that was it. I was planning on putting that meta tag in there at some point. I didn't realize that was the problem. Pls post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. So to better explain your issue, this specific [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994465/positionfixed-not-working-on-mobile-works-on-desktop) question can pretty much give you the gist behind it all. But as an easier explanation, your phone is telling the web that it is not designed for all websites and all the capabilities, however, with the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
```

this code will tell the HTML that it is designed for any type of styles incorporated with your website. But again, the stack question linked to this answer is a better reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css rules

```
body, html {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   font-size: 1em;
}
#main {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   font-size: 1em;
}
#header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   padding:5px;
   width: 100%;
   background: black;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
#content {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Note :Do not use px for the font-size instead of em .em gives you the default font-size of the browser!
Hope the answer!
[image]