# Glass pane all over the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Is there an easy way to have a "glass pane" all over the HTML page, regardless of zoom/slide events/platform/browser{mobile/desktop}?

By "easy" I mean something like pure CSS support, not a plug-in.

Fallback: plug-in advice might be useful as well.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a layer on top of everything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just mean a layer on top of everything, try this:

```
#top-layer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

You can set `opacity: 0.5;` if you want it semi-transparent.

[A jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gfMFC/)

Comment: in that case `height` will relate to viewport only, I'd like the scroll event to be supported as well (i.e. after scrolling down, the glass pane should remain visible and not just shift up).

Comment: do you know by chance - will `fixed` it support mobile browsers as well? AFAIK Mobile Safari on iOS5 might have probs with that.

Comment: [IOS5 has support](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5) for `position: fixed;`, other mobile platforms might complaint, so you can use [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll)

Comment: Look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784889/android-web-app-positionfixed-broken) or use iScroll as I've suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a class to do this.

```
div.glass-pane {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can change the height, width, top, and left position to make the "glass pane" only fit over a certain area.  Also you can add some color (rgba or hsla would be the best and create a glass effect).  The z-index will help if you want to create a modal box on top of the pane.  Then just use jQuery to add click events.

I recently published a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jgekomkdphbcbfpnfjgcmjnnhfikinmn) that uses this effect ([here is the source](https://github.com/jjNford/github-repositories)).

Answer (score 1):

A glass pane?
Try this CSS:

```
div#glassPane {
   height: 98%;
   width: 98%;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   border-radius: 10px;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
   box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   position: fixed;
   top: 1%;
   left: 1%;
}
```

See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vLTWK/

See here for more:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/beautiful-ui-styling-with-css3-text-shadow-box-shadow-and-border-radius/#glassbox

Comment: Yes, I just answered it - what are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to the fact that he does not merely mean a styled glass pane. But I can see you've edited your question now to include the fixed positioning he was talking about.

Comment: Ah - you were referring to that part about 'slide'?

Comment: looks beautiful! but doesn't occupy a full page on Android (only a fraction of it - just checked)

Comment: I'd wish I could explain the behavior of mobile browsers.