# Displaying a html table non-editable in javascript

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a form which gets input from user and when the user submit the form I do have a 'processing, please wait' gif image.

When the processing symbol is displaying, i want my table which gets input to be non-editable. [ kind of visible, but should be blurr or light colored ], Like it will be there in the internet backing page.

Is there a pre-defined functions  to achieve this? I dont want to use, disable text boxes or buttons while the user submits the form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are willing to use jquery, there is an excellent plugin JQuery BlockUI. You can use element blocking demoed here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#element

Comment: That should be the answer ^^^

Comment: @Manish: that is really nice. could you please post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1: JQuery Plugin**

The quick and easy solution for this would be to use a jquery plugin such as [jQuery BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/). There are a ton of similar plugins available, you can do a quick google search if you want to evaluate others.

**Approach 2: Plain Javascript/CSS**

If you want to do it with plain javascript and CSS, there is a solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778336/modal-dialog-without-jquery).