# Standalone javascript library to create modal dialogues

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, bootbox

I am looking for a lightweight library to create elegant modal dialogues with different purpose (alerts, confirmation, prompt, forms). A library similar to [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) but without JQuery and Bootstrap dependencies would be perfect.

**Note:** I already know how to create modals using native javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778336/modal-dialog-without-jquery), or using pure CSS [examples here](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-javascript-popup-window.html). I am looking for a library to facilitate this task.

Comment: https://github.com/tomloprod/tomloprodModal

Comment: There is [ModaliseJS](https://github.com/AlexisTM/modalise.js), lightning fast, with no dependencies and do only what it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `codepen` example that is pure CSS with no jQuery or Bootstrap dependencies: http://codepen.io/maccadb7/pen/nbHEg

and here is link to a "library" to create a "small & customizable modal" without jQuery or Bootstrap dependencies: http://www.cssscript.com/small-customizable-modal-dialog-javascript-library-nano-modal/

Comment: I already provided a link to this example in the question. I am looking for a lightweight library to create different styles of modals without having to code them one by one.

Comment: Here is a "library" to create a "small & customizable modal" without jQuery or Bootstrap dependencies: http://www.cssscript.com/small-customizable-modal-dialog-javascript-library-nano-modal/

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to do the job!!