# How to open a modal for a particular ID in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Bootstrap, to open a pop-up window, you do this, using jQuery:

`$('#edit_modal').modal();`

You call the `modal` function for this ID. What is the equivalent in vanilla JavaScript? I tried:

`document.getElementById("edit_modal").modal();`

and I get:

> document.getElementById(...).modal is not a function

What am I missing? How can I call a function for a particular ID?

Thanks.

Comment: `modal()` is a jQuery function.

Comment: Maybe are you finding this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778336/modal-dialog-without-jquery?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Actually it's a Bootstrap function which requires jQuery (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals). jQuery UI has a similar `dialog()` function however.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki The modal is an example. I am aksing how can I call a function for a particular id , in general, using vanilla js.

Comment: Pass the id/element into the function as an argument?

Comment: If you know that `modal` is not a method of HTML elements, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated in the comments, `.modal()` is a method specific to Bootstrap/jQuery, which is why you can't call it via "regular" JavaScript.

However, for standard DOM methods, your syntax would work. For example,

```
document.getElementById("edit_modal").focus();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("edit_modal").blur();
```

would both work fine with vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use several ways, try :

```
document.getElementById('elem_id')
document.getElementById('elem_id')[0]
document.querySelector('#elem_id')
document.querySelectorAll('#elem_id')[0]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second line returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

Since Materialize CSS now is not JQuery-dependent, the answer to your question is in their website:

```````
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
  });
``````

This is the link to their website: https://materializecss.com/modals.html
```````