# Android - Position sticky (CSS) not working in android webview

Tags: android, css, kotlin, webview, sticky

Well, the title says it all. The position sticky doesn't work when I do scroll in the `webview`. I just want to a header bar stays fixed at the top, but the sticky property loses is purpose. There is any solution too this?

Comment: have you found a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: Hi @ben. Nop, I just created the component in Kotlin and xml, and given up to do it in html and ccs.

Comment: I see, no worry then thanks! Probably too late for you but I'm about to try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784889/android-web-app-positionfixed-broken